# Asterisque on Kummer surfaces

Tags: bibliography

Hi all,

I have been looking for the volume on Asterisque about Kummer surfaces but I do not have all the information. Dose any one know which volume/year is it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have institutional access to MathSciNet: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=JOUR&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=kummer&s6=asterisque&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq

Comment: Or Zentralblatt http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/

Comment: Sorry, 1st URL not helpful without access. Try http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=785226

Comment: It's usually hard to a search without the author(s). However, I do
remember a volume by Beauville et. al. on  K3s (which include Kummer surfaces). So perhaps
Géométrie des surfaces K3: modules et périodes,
Astérisque No. 126 (1985) is what you want.

Comment: Donu: the first link is the unique MathSciNet search result for "journal = Asterisque" AND "title = Kummer" ...

Comment: Yemon, sorry, I hadn't checked your link. It looks like all roads are
leading to vol, 126!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, Asterisque 126 (1985):
mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=ISSI&s1=12429